# Linking and querying MySql with Play-1.2.5

Tags: mysql, sql, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using MySql and Play-1.2.5, I have linked the two using the following lines in application.conf,

```
# If you need a full JDBC configuration use the following :
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user="root"
db.default.password="pass"
db.default.url="mysql://localhost:3306/sample"
```

AFAIK, correct me if I am wrong, Play-1.2.5 does not provide any documentation for linking and querying database.

Now,

1. How do I setup Model class in play framework to access the database tables and its fields?
2. Is there a query interface(eg: MorphiaQuery for MongoDB) to perform CRUD operations on mysql database or using the actual mysql query is the only option?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of documentation and tutorials on the subject.
MySQL works out of the box with JPA.
For morphia and MongoDB you might want to use a module.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/jpa
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/guide2
http://mangstacular.blogspot.com/2011/09/play-framework-part-2-database.html

http://www.playframework.com/modules/morphia
http://www.playframework.com/modules/morphia